# Javascript setting cookies with path=/

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm creating cookies which are intended to be shared all across mysite.

This is the code that creates such cookies:

```
var setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    var path ="path=/;";
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";" + path;
};
```

It looks pretty straight forward, and I'm using `path=/` to indicate that I want to create or modify always the same cookie all along my site.

The problem is that it is creating one cookie for each URL. With a Mozilla plugin I can see the following:

```
Cookie Name         Value   Path
timer_is_enabled    true    /
timer_is_enabled    false   /foo
timer_is_enabled    true    /foo/bar
```

Which is causing my many bugs because the variables which are being accessed are not one and only, but many independent ones.

Any idea why I'm getting this behavior?

Comment: Just to ensure they aren't remnants from earlier tests, can you remove them all and try again?

Comment: You are right. I wasn't deleting all the cookies correctly. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I've composed a proper answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as expected, at least regarding the *path* attribute. Those other cookies may be remnants from earlier tests (sadly, there's normally no way to track the creation date of a given cookie since browsers don't normally keep such information).

I suggest you remove all current cookies from the browser and try again.

Answer (score 1):

That function works ok for me. Ran the following:

```
setCookie('myCookieKey', 'myCookieValue', 10);
```

And I got the following:

[image]